# python - cx_Freeze exe file detected as malware

Tags: python, cx-freeze, malware, virus

On every computer every AntiVirus-Software detects my exe with cx_Freeze 5.0.2 created exe file as malware. It doesn't matter what code is compiled, every code gets detected. Trying to go back and compile with cx_freeze 4.3 in Python 3.4 causes a lot of errors because of compatibility problems with my scripts.

What can I do? Things like py2exe do not work because of too much errors and Python 3.6.

Comment: Py2exe is for  Python 2 only do you won't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

**pyinstaller** package is the best one! see : http://www.pyinstaller.org/

you need to install pywin32 package too, then you can try this ( run this on your commandline ):

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=app.ico your_app.py
```

you can find all its commands on : https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html, https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script/